# CSP does not appear to be applied on inline script in an <object> with an SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, content-security-policy

I have an svg that I load inside HTML with an `<object>` element and I want to block inline scripts in the SVG with a CSP.

I use an `<object>` instead of inlining the SVG in the HTML because I reuse the SVG elsewhere, and I can't use an `<img>` because the SVG is interactive.

Here is a summary of my html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self';object-src 'self'">
  </head>
  <body>
    <object data='mySvg.svg' type='image/svg+xml'></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Contents of mySvg.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="30" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" onclick="alert('svg inline script executed!')"></circle>
</svg>
```

The problem is that if I test the CSP by including inline javascript in the SVG, the javascript gets executed even if the CSP is applied. I would expect that the javascript would be blocked. If I do not use my SVG in an `<object>` but inline instead, the CSP works as expected and blocks the javascript:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self';object-src 'self'">
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="30" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" onclick="alert('this script is blocked by CSP!')"></circle>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to apply the CSP on `<object>` elements to prevent inline scripts to be executed?

Comment: Which browser did you used? I tested your snippet in latest Chrome and Firefox. It was blocking the inline script as expected. I created a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nigevurizu/edit?html,output) containing the script to quickly test it.

Comment: I use the latest Chrome. You have tested my second html snippet, that's the one that is working as expected. The problem is with the first html snippet, in which the SVG is embedded in an `<object>` tag.